# F#: Providing type annotation for overloaded constructor

Tags: f#, type-providers

I'm getting a FS0041 error for an overloaded constructor, and I can't find my way around it.

Here are two screenshot of my attempts:

[image]

and:

[image]

How can I execute the desired constructor?

Comment: It looks like this service has three methods that take no arguments and differ only in their return types. (These aren't really constructors in the technical sense.) Unfortunately, you can't override a method based solely on its return type in F# (or C#). Can you post the WSDL that this type was generated from?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the actual WSDL, it looks to me that the service is not correctly designed. I think it should be something like this:

```
GetTUIProductServiceSoap(): TUIProductServiceSoapClient
GetTUIOrderServiceSoap(): TUIOrderServiceSoapClient
GetTUIUserActivateServiceSoap(): TUIUserActivateServiceSoapClient
```

That would eliminate the ambiguity.